# Struts2 namespace complex configuration

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2, struts2-namespace

I want to do something like this:

```
<a href"page1/login.action"> Link </a>
<a href"page2/login.action"> Link </a>
<a href"pagen/login.action"> Link </a>
```

Then every subfolder will use the same login, then I can create dynamic subfolder

How I have to configure struts.xml?
This doesn't work

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/*/">
  <action name="login" class="package/myclass">
  ...
</package>
```

Any idea?

Comment: the namespace cannot contain wild cards, you can say `namespace="page1"`

Comment: namespaces are a logical separation and wild-card will not work as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I do:

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
  <action name="login" class="package/myclass" method="initCampusList" >
    <result name="success" >/user/pickUser.jsp</result>
```

I have to put the absolute url of the result
Thanks for the answers

Comment: if this is the solution for your post, i suggest you to accept your own answer so that other can find out which one was rigth answr

Answer (score 0):

We cannot use wildcards in namespace. But u can use wild cards for action mappings.

Use struts url tag in jsp and use wildcards in the action names in struts.xml. see the reference http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/wildcard-mappings.html

```
<a href='<s:url name="page1/login.action" namespace="/">'> Link </a>
<a href='<s:url name="page2/login.action" namespace="/">'> Link </a>
```

Hope this will help you.